# Ci bonfire upload image fail to upload to destinated directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

it my first use ci bonfire
why my result the image not appear [this my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7eqH.png)

and this my controller

```
public function tambah(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './gambar/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '2000';
    $config['max_height']  = '1024';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('gambar')){
                $gambar="";
            }else{
                $gambar=$this->upload->file_name;
            }

            $info=array(
                'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
                'jenis'=>$this->input->post('jenis'),
                'nama'=>$this->input->post('nama'),
                'harga'=>$this->input->post('harga'),
                'pemasok'=>$this->input->post('pemasok'),
                'gambar'=>$gambar
            );
            $this->model_barang->input_data($info);
            redirect('barang/tampil');
}
```

there is my model, i think i don't find any error

```
<?php  class Model_barang extends CI_Model{
private $table="barang";
public function tampil_data(){
    return $this->db->get('barang');
}
public function input_data($jenis){
    $this->db->insert($this->table,$jenis);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
public function hapus($where,$table){
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    $row = $query->row();
    unlink('./gambar/'.$row->gambar);
    $this->db->delete($table,$where);
}
public function edit_data($where,$table) {
    return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
}
public function update($where,$data,$table){
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get($table);
    $row = $query->row();
    $this->db->where($where);
    unlink('./gambar/'.$row->gambar);
    $this->db->update($table,$data);
} }
```

this my form input

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(). 'index.php/barang/tambah'; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h3>Tambah Data Barang</h3></legend> <br />
            ID Barang <input type="text" name="id" required> <br /> <br />
            Jenis Barang
            <select name="jenis" class="form-control">
            <option value="Teknologi">Teknologi</option>
            <option value="Alat Petani">Alat Petani</option>
            <option value="Kebutuhan Rumah Tangga">Kebutuhan Rumah Tangga</option>
            <option value="Alat Tulis">Alat Tulis</option>
            <option value="Perabotan Sekolah">Perabotan Sekolah</option>
            </select><br /> <br />
            Nama Barang<input type="text" name="nama" required> <br /> <br />
            Harga Barang<input type="number" name="harga" required> <br /> <br />
            Pemasok<input type="text" name="pemasok" required> <br /> <br />
            <input type="file" name="gambar" value="<?php echo set_value('gambar', isset($barang['gambar']) ? $barang['gambar'] : ''); ?>"> <br /> <br />
            <button class="tombol">Tambah</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and there is my view data

```
<table style="margin:50px auto;" border="1" width="800" height="300" class="zebra-table">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Jenis</th>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>harga</th>
        <th>pemasok</th>
        <th>Gambar</th>
        <th>Aksi</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $no = 1;
    foreach($barang as $q){ 
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->jenis ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->nama ?></td>
        <td><?php echo currency_format($q->harga) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $q->pemasok ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('./gambar/'.$q->gambar);?>" height="100px" width="100px"></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor('barang/hapus/'.$q->id,'Hapus', ['onclick'=>'return confirm(\'Apakah Anda Yakin\')'] ); ?> | <?php echo anchor('barang/edit/'.$q->id,'Edit') ?></td>      
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

i don't know any error in this code

Answer (score 0):

if you do not receive an error during installation try it

```
<?php echo base_url('/gambar/'.$q->gambar);?>
```

or

```
<?php echo base_url('gambar/'.$q->gambar);?>
```

We dont know your base_url();

But I dont know your error. I guess there is an error in the image path.You can open new tab image path and you can check.